# What is the difference between There is at least one, Some, At least one when it comes to predicate logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

$A(x)$:$x$ is an apple.

$R(x)$: $x$ is red.

$G(x)$: $x$ is green

I need to translate the following sentence into their equivalent *logical form* using the above dictionary:

$1$. There is at least one red apple.

$2$. Some apples are red.

$3$. At least one apple is red.

The sentence I came up with for all of these is *$∃ x,A(x) ∧ R(x)$*

Are all these sentences seem different and does my sentence only fit to one of them?

Comment: They should all be the same.

Comment: Arranged differently words are, yet meaning the same have they.

Comment: Hey guys, How would you write this sentence "There are no green apples", I said **∀x (Ax → --Gx)**, but my friend said **∀x (Gx → --Ax)** , which one is correct?

Comment: I think I am correct, since if you apply the rules of implication, then my sentence holds.

Answer (score 2):

They are all the same and your answer is fine.  One might argue that in English the second statement guarantees that there are at least two different red apples, but that is not the normal mathematical way to read the sentence.  If you do read it as guaranteeing two different red apples you need a different transcription.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, all of the three statements are same and thus have a unique quantified statement.

Each of them can be rewritten as follows:

There exists some $x$ s.t. $x$ is an apple and $x$ is red.

*Note*: The existential quantifier $\exists $ is used for the phrases like 'for some', 'there exists' and ''there is a' etc.

In quantified notation; it is $\exists x, A(x)\land R(x)$ as obtained by you.

Comment: How "for some" should interpreted it as "at least"? With "at least" if it is true "for all" then "at least" is also true. But "some" means "a part but not all" so it would be false.